# Any tutorials for the 10Dof DfRobot IMU? ADXL345 - HMC5883L - ITG-3205 - BMP085

Tags: python, i2c, sensor, c

I would like to connect this Imu to the Raspberry Pi via **I2C**. I am looking for a **C/C++ or Python** code to use the data provided by this imu.

[image]

It integrates the

- ADXL345 accelerometer,
- HMC5883L magnetometer,
- ITG-3205 gyro
- BMP085 barometric pressure sensor.

It is perfect for a quadcopter application. There are a lot of tutorials for the Arduino but I haven't found any related to Raspberry.

Do you have any advice or good link?

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds of links available by googling.

Google for the sensor + raspberry + language (where sensor is one of ADXL345, HMC5883L, ITG3205, or BMP085).